# If I turn off my PC while downloading a game will the download restart?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale, epic-games-launcher

I'm downloading Fortnite and was wondering if I can turn off my PC while it's downloading. What would happen if I turned off my PC?

Comment: Are you shutting down or hard power-off? (not that that really affects the answer - I'm just curious!)

Answer (score 2):

When you restart the Epic Games Launcher - even if it got force-closed, and/or you restarted Windows or your laptop in the meantime - it will continue any downloads it was working on before it was closed.
Note that they - obviously - won't continue downloading while your laptop is shut off.